# Leaflet - Icon-Layer-Switch

Tags: leaflet

I am currently creating an interactive map for a class at my University. As I am just a beginner in coding, I have some trouble achieving what I have in mind. I would like to create a layer-switch such as the one presented here : https://github.com/ScanEx/Leaflet-IconLayers.

I unfortunately don't understand everything in this example, and so I have trouble adding it to my own map.

When I tried just copying the code and adding it to my map, most of what I had won't appear anymore (such as the markers and the infopopup).

Here is my project : https://github.com/TheBearMan93/Projet-1.

If someone could help me resolve my problem I would be really grateful.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you include some of the code that you attempted to add that is causing you problems?

Comment: I added this <script> to my index.html under the <div id="map"> :
      <script>
          var mymap = L.map('map').setView([39.8, -95.49], 5);

          var layers = [];
          for (var providerId in providers) {
              layers.push(providers[providerId]);
          }
          var ctrl = L.control.iconLayers(layers).addTo(mymap);
      </script>

I also added the different .js and .css from the example to my <head>. Unfortunately, when I did that, the layer switcher appeared and is working, but everything else I need disappeared (markers, popup, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the leaflet Icon layer switch, you are are going to want to create an object of baseLayers which includes the name, icon, and layer like this.

```
var providers = {};

providers['OpenStreetMap_Mapnik'] = {
    title: 'osm',
    icon: './images/icons/openstreetmap_mapnik.png',
    layer: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    })
};
```

Then rather than using the standard leaflet layer control, you will use the icon-layer-switch library. This loops through all of the providers you define creates the layer control and adds to the map.

```
var layers = [];
for (var providerId in providers) {
    layers.push(providers[providerId]);
}
layers.push({
    layer: {
        onAdd: function() {},
        onRemove: function() {}
    },
    title: 'empty'
})
var ctrl = L.control.iconLayers(layers).addTo(mymap);
```

I've created a pull request on your github project to see how this could work for you.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @Nicolas You're welcome. If the answer worked for you, can you please mark it as accepted :)